# Game Development: Automatic Testing of OpenGL and DirectX

Tags: testing, opengl, directx, automated-tests

I'm writing my Master's thesis on automatic portability testing and was wondering whether there were any automatic testing software for game developers when they're developing a game with both OpenGL and DirectX support? Theoretically one could record the screen during the automatic run of a specific sequence in the game and analyze both OpenGL and DirectX recordings but is there some technical aspect which makes this impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of are the tests in Wine, which do something along these lines.

Unfortunately, proper testing like this isn't possible; the tests are far too dependent on system state and implementations aren't guaranteed to be pixel-identical. DirectX does offer the reference implementation, which can be used for many testing uses, but I don't know of an OpenGL equivalent.

Recording the screen introduces even more error, depending on how it's performed. The tests I've seen render an image, then work from the texture data (similar to screen recording, but on a single frame and potentially more precise). Still, the whole thing is prone to quite a bit of error and can be slow.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell from your question, you are trying to compare the rendering results of an OpenGL and a DirectX renderer, rendering the same scene.

The only thing I can think of to do that is rendering the scene to textures in both renderers and either save them uncompressed for later comparison or have an intermediate render path that takes both textures and a shader to render the per-pixel-difference into another texture to be evaluated later.

However, the usefulness of such a comparison is debatable in my opinion as it's hard to automatically tell if an error is just a slight discrepancy in implementation or an actually visible artifact, let alone evaluating the importance of an error regarding the users perception.

And this already assumes you are able to have both renderers run at exactly the same frame rate and camera position, which is unlikely.

I guess you would have a lot of noise and offset in your error images to account for to actually find any useful information, if at all.

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly. Frame rates etc. surely introduce a lot of variables which make the testing more difficult. There could of course be a tolerance setting so that if two specific images differ by some specific amount, the image is sent for a human reviewer. Unfortunately the automatic process may be so error prone that there probably isn't enough profits for implementing one.

Answer (score 0):

I know that screen comparisons where done some 15 (?) years ago for different graphic chips, you would need to search for image quality metrics, I guess.